# How to change subtile dynamically on PlaybackTransportControlGlue android TV

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-tv, leanback

I am building a video player app for Android TV. I am using Exoplayer leanback dependency as explained in https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/transport-controls.
So far I've been able to display the video title, which is static, but I need to display a subtitle that is dynamic, it changes whenever the video playing changes. How can I do it?
The image below shows how the video player looks like. I've used a subtitle phrase as a placeholder on where it should appear.

[image: Screenshot on Android TV]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. I added a listener in the VideoSupportFragment class, Player.EventListener.
This way:

```
class VideoFragment(mediaItems: Map<String, Any>) : VideoSupportFragment(), Player.EventListener {
private var playerAdapter: ExoPlayerAdapter? = null
private var _mediaItems: Map<String, Any>? = null
private lateinit var mMediaPlayerGlue: VideoMediaPlayerGlue<ExoPlayerAdapter>
private var mItems: List<*>? = null

init {
    _mediaItems = mediaItems
}

private val mHost: VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost = VideoSupportFragmentGlueHost(this)
private fun playWhenReady(glue: PlaybackGlue) {
    if (glue.isPrepared) {
        glue.play()
    } else {
        glue.addPlayerCallback(object : PlaybackGlue.PlayerCallback() {
            override fun onPreparedStateChanged(glue: PlaybackGlue) {
                if (glue.isPrepared) {
                    glue.removePlayerCallback(this);
                    glue.play()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val mediaSource = _mediaItems?.get("media_source") as Map<*, *>
    playerAdapter = ExoPlayerAdapter(activity!!, _mediaItems!!)
    mMediaPlayerGlue =
        VideoMediaPlayerGlue(activity, playerAdapter!!)
    mMediaPlayerGlue.host = mHost;
    mMediaPlayerGlue.isControlsOverlayAutoHideEnabled = true
    mItems = mediaSource["media_items"] as List<*>
    mMediaPlayerGlue.title = mediaSource["title"] as CharSequence?

    mMediaPlayerGlue.playerAdapter.setDataSource()
    mMediaPlayerGlue.isSeekEnabled = true
    playerAdapter?.player?.addListener(this);

    playWhenReady(mMediaPlayerGlue)
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    playerAdapter?.player?.pause()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    playerAdapter?.player?.play()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    playerAdapter?.player?.removeListener(this);
}

override fun onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) {
    if (mItems?.size!! > 1){
        val item : Map<*, *> = mItems!![playerAdapter?.player?.currentWindowIndex!!] as Map<*, *>
        mMediaPlayerGlue.subtitle = item["subtitle"] as String
    }
}
```

}